# Python: How do I create 2x2 array with NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want 2x2 array which I want to add elements. I use numpy. What am I doing wrong??
For example:

```
for i in range(len(pin)):
    for k in range(len(pin)):
        sumv = 0
        for j in range(len(pin[i])):
            sumv = sumv + ...
            c = np.data(sumv).reshape(len(pin),len(pin))
print c
```

Output:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'

What should I write?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `np.data` would be useful?  Sounds like you skipped the basic numpy documentation.

Comment: According to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

Comment: I have put this. Do you have to suggest something else? How can I do this?

Comment: `data` is an attribute of an existing numpy array (i.e. an instance of the `ndarray` class).  That is, once you have created a numpy array, say `a`, you can use `a.data`.  In your code, you are referencing `numpy.data`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: See [the online documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html) for information about creating a numpy array.

Comment: Deleted my weak comment in favor of WarrenW's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

> ndarray.data
>
> the buffer containing the actual elements of the array. Normally, we won’t need to use this attribute because we will access the elements in an array using indexing facilities.

Your `quickstart` describes attributes of an `ndarray` object, that is, an array. But `np` is the `numpy` module. `a=np.array(....)` creates an `ndarray` object. Its `.shape` and `.dtype` are important attributes. `.data` is something you should know about, but rarely reference directly.

The best way to start with numpy is to make an array like:

```
In [592]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [593]: a
Out[593]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

which can be manipulated like:

```
In [594]: a[1,:]
Out[594]: array([3, 4])
In [595]: a[0,1]
Out[595]: 2
In [596]: np.concatenate((a,a), axis=0)
Out[596]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [597]: np.concatenate((a,a), axis=1)
Out[597]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 3, 4]])
```

Or if you want to make an array iteratively, start with lists

```
In [598]: alist = []
In [599]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     sublist = []
     ...:     for j in range(2):
     ...:         sublist.append(i+j)
     ...:     alist.append(sublist)     
In [600]: alist
Out[600]: [[0, 1], [1, 2]]
In [601]: a=np.array(alist)
In [602]: a
Out[602]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```